# Hosting A Website

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, apache2

So what I have been trying for 2 months now a few hours a day. And failed miserably.

What I and trying to achieve is I have a lots of spear computers at home so this is no problem.

My home internet connection is 1GB download and upload speed. And can be upgraded to 1.5GB UP and  Down.

I want to basically setup a web server like a vps running Ubuntu because I want to run a Wordpress site and a online radio station that is open free https://www.azuracast.com that I want to install on my own server as I am paying £80 a month for azuraradio.uk and Krystal.uk that is shared hosting but it is amazing for customer service and the website speed. However the worst specs computer I could use here is still better than what I am using with there hosting package.

So ideally I want to be able to use it like a dedicated hosting package. That you buy from a hosting company where you buy a package and install whatever operating system such as Archlinux, Centos, Debian, Fedora, FreeBSD 12 ZFS, Ubuntu ect. So I can login anywhere and use as if I had a hosting company.

So ideally I want somewhere what I can basically have like krystal.uk where you can purchase a VPS package host 2 WordPress installations and azuracast and make a droplet to install it on.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LjKca14Di38 this video explains how to add to a server.

Can anybody help I am losing my temper with myself.

Answer (score 0):

I did this in the past and best option is to have a virtual environment platform installed to take care of these VPSs

There are many opensource ones, I liked https://www.proxmox.com/en/downloads because it does almost everything you asked above compared to other control panels only such as the great https://vestacp.com/ which is also opensource.

And of course there is the old webmin with its sister virtualmin

Good luck.

Comment: thank you for your reply but I and not very good at this I have build a computer pacifically to host sites on. I have installed proxmox. I and Ubuntu server with a visual machine within proxmox. I have no idea how to use it I don't no much coding. I wanted to host my own website and the https://www.azuracast.com from there. I have many domain names with go daddy. I want something like when you purchase hosting say like cPanel where you login add a domain. change named servers. So I need something that I can assign a domain name and login anywhere.

Comment: And so it does everything for you. Rather than been on a local host and attach a domain name to the host.All I want to do is host 2 Wordpress site and the Azuracast from. I am so confused.

Comment: you will need to setup nameservers (DNS servers) to enable domains point to your IP, alternatively you can use dynamic IP services like no-ip.com or dyndns.org if you don't have a staic IP